# How to simulate slow internet connection

Tags: browser, browser-addons, python, internet-connection, google-app-engine

I currently deploy with GAE (google app engine) and I try to implement some AJAX validation. So I got a couple text-fields and "spinners" (ajax loaders) which should be displayed when an AJAX request is sent. But I deploy on my local computer (localhost), so the GAE SDK reacts very fast on any request. It takes about 50-70 ms(miliseconds) to perform the whole ajax request, which is far far away from the real.

Is there a way to somehow **simulate** slow Internet connection? I just want to see how my "spinners" work. I want to test some ajax setting (jquery) about timeouts, errors and so on...

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are looking for a latency simulator. A search for that term should return something useful.

Comment: what is your current internet speed? which speed do you want to have (approximately)?

Comment: ADSL (~ 8000 KBit/s Down). There is a nice feature in adobe's flash Player. If you develop an Pre-Loader with AS you can easy test it in flash player with different speed (kind of Dual-Up, ISBN and DSL 1000 simulation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a browser to simulate that, you can use Firefox Throttle, Internet Explorer Throttle or Fiddler.

Comment: Fiddler did the trick. At least i was able to test the AJAX request @ Dual-Up Modem Speed.

Comment: Link [1] is dead

Comment: @tuxayo, thank you. The same occurred to link [2] (now it points to a hosting service - it normally happens when the domain is abandoned). I asked meta.stackoverflow.com about it and I'll correct the answer later.

Comment: I removed the links. Later, I would improve the answer (or someone else post a better and updated answer).

Answer (score 5):

Using linux you have a software called [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) that launches a process and limits its bandwidth usage.

Comment: I'll take a look...
but, actually, i'm using kinda 'complicated' system. I run Ubuntu in Win7 (vmware) and use GAE. The reason is - linux command line and no need to install python under windows.  But sometimes its getting to much for my laptop (IDE, 2 browsers, bash...and thats all virtualy) so i decided to use my internal IP so i can access the GAE development 'server' from windows. Like http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8181/myApp/ So i, actually, deploy in Windows but it all runs in Ubuntu...So I don't know if **trickle** can handle with this

Comment: It's not clear what is virtual on what. If you run Firefox inside Ubuntu inside vmware inside Win7, just call Firefox by `trickle -d 10 firefox`. If it's the other way around, you may try `trickle -d 10 vmware` to launch Win7 inside Ubuntu, but I can't say for sure how it will work.

Comment: Win7 is Host (OS which runs virtualization software -vmware workstation 7). Ubuntu 10.10 is a Guest OS. Python and GAE is installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: So did `sudo apt-get install trickle && trickle -d 10 firefox` work? You can test it by downloading a big file from a fast server. Make sure firefox is closed when you run this.

Answer (score 4):

I would check out [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).  It has bandwidth throttling and is cross-platform with a very clean interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is free and simple for Mac OS X and works with the every browser: [speedlimit](https://github.com/mschrag/speedlimit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "slow Internet connection" from a mobile phone (for example, GPRS). You must have a mobile phone that become a modem when connected to the PC and a carrier that provides that kind of connection.

For example, I can connect my LG phone in my computer and use a dial-up program (provided by LG) to perform a connection in TIM, my carrier. So, my internet connection is about 40kbps.

You will have a slow connection, but you cannot adjust its speed only with that.

Comment: Although a good idea, it doesn't really answer the question on how to **simulate** a slow connection. In fact, it **is** a slow connection.

Comment: I agree. "To use a simulated slow solution" is different than "to use a real slow solution", because on the first case you probably would have more control on connection speed. But for that particular case where developer is using a computer that can use different internet connection types (wi-fi, rj45...) with different speeds, it is easier to simply change the connection in use than searching and installing particular solutions. Well, it is an alternative.

Comment: It answers the question on an alternative way - like a HW+procedure way where it is expected a SW+programming way.