# How to slowdown my internet connection to simulate 3G, WIFI, etc?

Tags: macos, speed, internet-connection

I wonder how can I slowdown my internet connection to test my application (not web application)?

If I were at the browser I would use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/297103/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection), but that is not the case. I want to test cocoa/cocoa-touch applications that run in MacOSX and the iOS simulator

Comment: Bear in mind that lower bandwidth is only part of the story when it comes to mobile data connections. The higher latency is likely to be much more important, particularly from the user experience point of view.

Comment: You should also take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox

Answer (score 3):

Use [speed limit](http://mschrag.github.com/).  It slows done your internet connection on mac OSX for testing.

N.B. I have just come across a similar [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593971/iphone-simulator-simulate-a-slow-connection).