# Need a free Windows tool to insert arbitrary network delay at transport level

Tags: windows, networking, delay

I am working on a problem where I suspect there is an issue with network delay and timeouts. I currently can't reproduce it because I am unable to reproduce the delay part quite the way I want. Is there a tool available I can use to just arbitrarily delay outgoing network traffic by x seconds?

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/297103/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a tool, but conceptually, you have to do one of two things.

1. Route all traffic though a proxy (hosted locally) that will hold onto it for a certain time stretch and then send it on.
2. Change the driver somehow so that it delays the traffic.

I would definitely go for option 1.