# How to implement delay in serving network request in windows environment?

Tags: windows, networking, smb, cifs

I have read [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/320494/need-a-free-windows-tool-to-insert-arbitrary-network-delay-at-transport-level) but did not find an appropriate reply, hence I am posting this question.

I have a scenario where my Windows client is an anti-virus server.  To reproduce a bug, I need to hold the client side CIFS request by introducing some delay of 5-10 sec.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: My crystal ball sent me to ask you: What protocol are you talking about? :)

Comment: Related/other possible dupes: http://superuser.com/questions/330501/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-or-limit-the-bandwidth-that-firefox-can-us, http://superuser.com/questions/297103/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection, http://superuser.com/questions/147156/simulating-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-network-connection-on-linux

Comment: CIFS protocol ...

Comment: thanks for the possible solution but seems none of them answer my query.

Comment: I already referred the first link which queries  same question but I am not sure how to route traffic to proxy server.

Comment: @Rahulanand: Then edit your question to focus on what exactly you want to know. How can people guess that your inability to implement soandos' proxy routing suggestion is the real issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if for CIFS, but if it was HTTP, I would write a simple CGI script.

In theory, the same approach could be used with CIFS, but even the most simple scenario (in terms as how the request should look? Does it need to be authorized properly?) might be pretty complicated to program.  The answers you refer seem easier to me...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another approach, to avoid scripting of CIFS client:  Somehow set up a "proper" CIFS  so that client will "believe" it and make it use resource from a virtual filesystem that uses HTTP as an underlying protocol.  (I'm thinking about something based on fuse might exist?)

Then just go for the simple CGI script.

Comment: I don't see how these answers are so radically different that you couldn't have merged them.

Comment: @Karan I don't see how merging answers is beneficial in the first place.

Comment: In general I follow [Jeff's advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25211/209972). The only time IMO multiple answers by the same person makes sense is if they approach the problem from *completely* different directions. Otherwise it's bound to be seen as a means to garner extra votes. A comprehensive canonical answer is always preferable.